# jquery - how to get form elements inside table

Tags: jquery

I'm usually use this code to get all form elements:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form')[0]; 
for (i = 0; i < form.elements.length; i++) 
{
    if (form.elements[i].type == 'file') 
    {
        if (form.elements[i].value == '') {
            form.elements[i].parentNode.removeChild(form.elements[i]);
        }
    }
}
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.push({name: 'act', value: 'edit'});
```

but now my form is inside a table row, and because of that i'm getting this error: `TypeError: form is undefined`

here is example of my html code (the form contain text field, textarea, and file). how do i post the form (i'm trying to use ajax)

```
<form action='#' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>   
    <tr id="4" class="fadeSec item">
        <td class="item_logo"><input name="file[]" type="file"></td>
        <td class="item_name"><input name="agnt[name]" value="Agency 2" type="text"><span>*</span></td>
        <td class="item_mainEmail"><input name="agnt[mainEmail]" value="email@gmail.com" type="text"></td>
        <td class="item_contact"><textarea type="text" name="agnt[contact]">some details</textarea></td>
        <td class="panel-menu">
            <div class="edit_msg"></div>

            <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-2x fa-fw edit_form-loader"></i>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-success edit_save-btn">Save</a>

        </td>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Comment: I would say that your form is not inside a table row. The table row is is inside the form.

Comment: Jquery `closest` does not return an array when points to a single element `$(this)`

Comment: @AliSheikhpour - OK, so how can i get all the form elements values? i would like to post the form via ajax....

Comment: Just try removing `[0]` @Roi